# Display Multiple MYSQL Query in PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have 3 queries. I want all 3 of them to run at one time and display the result. Here is my code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect ,"SELECT w2.Avis as Avis,w2.Cde_Sap,w2.Don_Ordre,w2.Num_cde_cl,w2.PN_in ,w2.SN_in,w2.DATE2,w2.Statut_Cde,client.Zone
 FROM w2
 INNER JOIN client
 ON w2.Don_Ordre = client.Client 
 WHERE client.Zone='AFZ' 

 UNION ALL

 SELECT w3.Avis,w3.Cde_Sap,w3.Don_Ordre,w3.Num_cde_cl,w3.PN_in ,w3.SN_in,w3.DATE2,w3.Statut_Cde,client.Zone
FROM w3
INNER JOIN client
ON w3.Don_Ordre = client.Client 
WHERE client.Zone='AFZ'

ORDER BY Avis DESC;") ;
```

Query 2

```
$query2= "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(w2.Statut_Cde, ' ', -1) FROM w2;";
```

Query 3

```
$query3 = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(w3.Statut_Cde, ' ', -1) FROM w3;" ;
```

Table display

```
<?php

while($w2= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo"<tr>";

    echo"<td>".$w2['Avis']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['Cde_Sap']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['Don_Ordre']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['Num_cde_cl']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['PN_in']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['SN_in']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['DATE2']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['Statut_Cde']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w2['Zone']."</td>";
//  echo"<td>".$w2['Comment']."</td>";

}//end while 
while($w3= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo"<tr>";

    echo"<td>".$w3['Avis']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['Cde_Sap']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['Don_Ordre']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['Num_cde_cl']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['PN_in']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['SN_in']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['DATE2']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['Statut_Cde']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$w3['Zone']."</td>";
//  echo"<td>".$w3['Comment']."</td>";

}//end while 

?>
```

Help with the execution of 3 queries.

Comment: What went wrong? Do you have errors? We need more details.

Comment: @Scoutman It shows : Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string on line 26 . 
I need help in passing multiple queries . I am not able to pass query 1,2,3 all together .